# Write file if exist or create file if not in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

my problem is that on local, my code works fine but when I pushed it on the server, the file isn't created.
Here's the code:

```
def write_binary_file(bfile, location):
    """Write binary file in the location"""
    try:
        with open(location, "wb+") as img_file:
            img_file.write(bfile)
    except IOError as err:
        Handling error

file_url = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, "dir", "dir", "dir", "dir", "user_img", filename + '.jpeg')
write_binary_file(bfile, file_url):
```

Difference between local and server: 
_local os is windows
_server os is linux

I don't know if this matter or not since I'm using `os.path.join` and `os.path.sep` to build the url and getting file url without the first dir.

It worked before in the server but one day, somehow, it didn't work anymore till now

space left on the server: about 3Go
permission on the directory: 775 (rwxrwxr-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, figured what was the problem, it was nginx config to hide file path in the server